# How to launch PDF file in associated app in HoloLens UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, hololens

I'm trying to open a PDF file, packaged inside app folder ("Assets"), in HoloLens (C#) app.

```
        string imageFile = @"Assets\test.jpg";

        var file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(imageFile);

        Debug.WriteLine("Opening file in path :" + file.Path);

        if (file != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("File found\nLaunching file...");

            var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
            options.DisplayApplicationPicker = true;
            // Launch the retrieved file
            var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);

            if (success)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("File launched successfully");
                // File launched
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("File launch failed");
                // File launch failed
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Could not find file");
            // Could not find file
        }
```

Getting `Access is Denied` error.

```
Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at SchneiderDemoLibrary.HoloHelper.<DefaultLaunch>d__3.MoveNext() Exception caught.
```

Can someone help me to solve this issue? I simply want to open some file with the corresponding app associated with the file type.

Comment: Have you tried `Process.Start(pdfFile)`?

Comment: @JamesHughes there is no `Process.Start` in Universal Windows Apps.

Comment: Got it working. I was trying to run this code from Unity 3D. Now I've created 2D window dynamically and triggered the above code on 2D window load.

Comment: @VinothkumarArputharaj How did you create 2D window dynamically? Am also trying to do the same, shed some light please

Answer (score 1):

1. Verify that the file is included in your project, and that the Build Action is set to "Content".
2. Switch to retrieving the `IStorageFile` reference via the `StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync` call.

The following code is working for me in a regular UWP application:

```
private async void OpenPdfButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync
    (
        new Uri("ms-appx:///Content/output.pdf")
    );

    await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
}
```